# How to fetch XML data from URL and parse it to combobox? C#

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

How can I bind XML from web into combobox in C#?

I have some XML file what look like this:

```
<value>
<name>James</name>
<id>007</id>
</value>

<value>
<name>Andy</name>
<id>008</id>
</value>
```

In Visual Basic it should look like this but in C#?:

```
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    ds.ReadXml("http://example.com/some.xml")


    With Me.ComboBox1
        .DataSource = cs.Tables("value")
        .DisplayMember = "name"
        .ValueMember = "id"
    End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `C#` version would be something like this:

```
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load("http://example.com/some.xml");

var values = xmlDocument
            .Descendants("value")
            .Select(x =>
                new
                {
                    name = (string) x.Element("name"),
                    id = (string) x.Element("id")
                }).ToList();


ComboBox1.DataSource = values;
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
```